# Incorrect file creation/modication time in linux

Tags: linux, time, date

In our server we get files uploaded daily by customers via FTP. However sometime the the time stamp of these appear incorrect even though the server time is correct. I got a file with time stamp **Jun 27** when actually the date was **Jun 25**. The server time was correct. Any idea about what is causing this ?

Comment: Uploaded how? HTTP? FTP? NFS? SMB? SCP? rsync? WebDAV?....? What software runs server-side?

Comment: uploaded via FTP

Answer (score 4):

This can also come from the client having an incorrect time.